# Creating An Object Field In Sequelize

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I am new to Sequelize, coming from MongoDB and mongoose, in a mongoose schema you can do this to save an object field in the schema,

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  age: String,
  address: {} // this right here
 })
```

Now my question is, how can I achieve such in Sequelize?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON datatype of field in Sequelize (this corresponds to JSON datatype in PostgreSQL).

```
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  age: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  },
  address: {
    type: DataTypes.JSON
  }
}, {
});
```

That way you can write to `address` field any JS-object (including an array).

Comment: Quick information: I recommend using a new table for addresses, using JSON as a property in sequelize is not very good for data querying and handling later.

Comment: Depends on tasks. If this field won't be used for sorting/filtering and can have quite dynamic structure then JSON can be suitable very well.King Etiosasere, please clarify how you plan to use this field

Comment: This ```address``` field is for storing the different address of users, which practically doesn't change much except the user edits and update the address information.

Comment: If a number of kinds of addresses is all known beforehand, stable and can be searchable then I recommend to use a separate table for them as Alcides Bezerra already mentioned